# Best way to duplicate elements in 2d array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays that look something like this:

```
let arr = [
  ["Rhonda", "Great Britain", 1, "Coffee", "Roasted"],
  ["Greg", "United States", 2, "Sugar", "Brown"],
  ["Bob", "Australia", 1, "Bread", "White"],
];
```

I would like to duplicate the individual arrays, with the number of duplicates based on the element in the 2nd position. Also would like to choose what elements in the first 3 positions. This is the desired result:

```
let result = [
  ["Rhonda", "Great Britain", 1, "Coffee", "Roasted"],
  [" ", " ", " ",  "Coffee", "Roasted"],
  ["Greg", "United States", 2, "Sugar", "Brown"],
  [" ", " ", " ", "Sugar", "Brown"],
  [" ", " ", " ", "Sugar", "Brown"],
  ["Bob", "Australia", 1, "Bread", "White"],
  [" ", " ", 1, "Bread", "White"],
];
```

I don't believe Splice is the correct method in this instance, as this is the result I'm currently getting:

```
[[Bob, Australia], [Bob, Australia], 
[Rhonda, Great Britain, 1.0, Coffee, Roasted], 
[Bob, Australia], [Greg, United States, 2.0, Sugar, Brown], 
[Bob, Australia, 1.0, Bread, White]]
```

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
let multiplier = arr[i][2];
arr.splice(multiplier, 0, [arr[i][0], arr[i][1]]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Array.flatMap` for that

```js
let arr = [
  ["Rhonda", "Great Britain", 1, "Coffee", "Roasted"],
  ["Greg", "United States", 2, "Sugar", "Brown"],
  ["Bob", "Australia", 1, "Bread", "White"],
];


const result = arr.flatMap(([first, second, num, ...rest]) => 
[
   [first, second, num, ...rest],
   ...Array.from({length: num}, () => ["", "", "", ...rest])
])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May not be the BEST way to do the duplicates but it will give you an idea.

The following code assumes that there will always be a number at the second position of the original array.

Try:

```js
const temp = []; // create an empty array to store the results

// loop the original array
arr.forEach(item => {
    // store the original item
    temp.push(item);

    // Check if the second element in the original contains a number  > 0
    if (item[2] > 0) {
        let count = 0;
        // Repeat until the count is > item[2]
        while (item[2] > count) {
            // add the new items to the temp array
            temp.push([" ", " ", item[3], item[4]]);
            count += 1;
        }
    }
});

console.log(temp);
```

Result

```js
[
  [ 'Rhonda', 'Great Britain', 1, 'Coffee', 'Roasted' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', 'Coffee', 'Roasted' ],
  [ 'Greg', 'United States', 2, 'Sugar', 'Brown' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', 'Sugar', 'Brown' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', 'Sugar', 'Brown' ],
  [ 'Bob', 'Australia', 1, 'Bread', 'White' ],
  [ ' ', ' ', 'Bread', 'White' ]
]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question,we can use `forEach` to do it:

1. find the repeat value and index of it
2. using repeat value and index to add duplicate value(had better to use `selice()` to do it)

```js
const isNumeric = (num) => (typeof(num) === 'number' || typeof(num) === "string" && num.trim() !== '') && !isNaN(num)

let arr = [
  ["Rhonda", "Great Britain", 1, "Coffee", "Roasted"],
  ["Greg", "United States", 2, "Sugar", "Brown"],
  ["Bob", "Australia", 1, "Bread", "White"],
]

let result =[]

arr.forEach(a1 => {
 let repeat = 0,index=0
 
 //find index and repeat count
 a1.forEach((a2,i2) => {
   if(isNumeric(a2)){
      repeat = a2
      index = i2
   }
 })
 
 result.push(a1)
 
 // using slice() might be a better choice
 for(let i=0;i<repeat;i++){
   let a =[]
   for(let j=0;j<index;j++){
     a.push(" ")
   }
   for(let j=index;j<a1.length;j++){
     a.push(a1[j])
   }
   result.push(a)
 }
 
})

console.log(result)
```